# Android: How to put the launcher icon in the first position

Tags: android, icons

I'm trying to put the launcher icon of my app in the first position of applications menu.

Apparently Android uses the name to do an ascendent order but there are apps that break this rule.

Take a look at the print. The NQ Mobile Security is the first app in my screen but it starts with "N"

http://apps.movile.com.s3.amazonaws.com/test/Screenshot_2013-09-13-17-56-19.png

How can i do the same thing ?

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 3):

Put a space or two in the begining of your application name.

In that case, if Alphabetic order is selected, yours will be first.